# What units are the stream initiation threshold in the SAGA channel network plugin in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis

I am using Qgis 3 and creating a Depth to Water (DTW) model and I am using NAD83 UTM 20. One of the steps in the creation of this model is delineating a stream network. In order to do so, I need to define the thresholds. The methods I am using defines the thresholds in hectares (ha). I want to develop multiple scenarios with stream networks with initiation thresholds of 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2 and 4 ha.

I was previously using 1 m DEMs but when working with large areas I prefer using a 5 m DEM to cut processing times.

In the saga channel network tool, what unit is the stream initiation threshold? Is it metres or pixels?

For example, when calculating a 1 ha initiation threshold using 1 m DEM, I type 10,000 in the channel initiation threshold parameter. For the 5 m DEM, I did the same thing and the results seem almost identical. If I am working in the 5 m DEM and I wanted a channel network with a 1 ha threshold, would I input 10,000 as well? Or if it’s by pixels would a 1 ha threshold for the 5 m DEM be 2,000 (10,000/5 m pixels)?

I have a feeling since I am working in NAD83 that the threshold units are metres. The results I am getting suggest that but I just want to make sure.

Comment: The unit is square meters, not meters... sorry for being a nitpicker. Anyway, 10,000 should work for 5m DEM, too.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant and nitpickers are welcome.